# Web push by OneSignal not alert with sound

Tags: magento, push-notification, onesignal

I using *OneSignal* for *Magento 2* to receive notification. That *show alert box **but no sound***. *How to alert with sound?*

This code used in magento module.

> *CODE*

```
public function sendMessageToAdmin($oneSignClient) {

    $content      = $oneSignClient->getContent();
    $headings     = $oneSignClient->getHeading();
    $data         = $oneSignClient->getData();

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => $this->_helper->getOneSignalAppIdForAdmin(),
        'data'     => $data,
        'contents' => $content,
        'headings' => $headings,
        'aps' => array("sound" => "sound.wav")
    );

    $fields['included_segments'] = array('All');
    $fields = json_encode($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic '. $this->_helper->getOneSignalKeyForAdmin()
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```